# How to run .command file extension in Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, bash

I have downloaded a backup application for my smartwatch but I can't execute the file. It says

"Go to the folder with the uncompressed files in terminal and run "bash amazebkp.command", then follow instructions."

However, I receive following message when I do that:

```
Device not detected! Please re-connect the watch to the computer.
amazebkp.command: line 368: adb: command not found
amazebkp.command: line 369: adb: command not found
```

Need your help to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script apparently requires the [`adb`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/adb)(*Android Debug Bridge*) package… That can be installed like so:

```
sudo apt install adb
```